# Copy files without changing owner

Tags: debian, files, backup

How to copy all files from `/var/www` onto a flash disk without changing owners of folders in the `/var/www` folder? (Or how to insert the whole `/var/www` folder into an archive and put it onto  a flash disk)

My system:

Debian 6 (Linux PSB1 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Mon Sep 23 23:00:18 UTC 2013 i686)

Comment: What filesystem do you have on the flash disk? This will very much depend on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cp -rp /var/www/ /path/to/flash/disk/
```

From cp manpage:

```
-p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
      preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps),
      if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

Comment: it's very unlikely that a flash drive is formatted with `ext2/ext3/ext4`

Answer (score 2):

First mount your usb.

```
 $ mkdir -p /mnt/myusb
 $ mount -t vfat -o rw,users /dev/sda1 /mnt/myusb
 $ mount
```

After that you can use rsync command to do this wirh -avz arguments

```
rsync -avz /var/www /mnt/myusb
```

This will keep permissions, owner and links of /var/www .

Answer (score 1):

You must be root (or have CAP_CHOWN and CAP_FOWNER and probably also CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE, and CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH) in order to do that. Then it is simple: `cp -a`

Answer (score 0):

If your filesystem is capable of preserving the ownership information, then `cp -a` (archive) preserves all parameters (permission, ownership, links, extended attributes).

Comment: it's very unlikely that a flash drive is formatted with ext2/ext3/ext4